# How to add fields like Text1, Text2 or Number1 Number2 to Formula in Enterprise Custom Fields for Reporting in Project Online/ Project server

Tags: rest, project-server, project-online, powerbi

How to add fields like Text1, Text2 or Number1 Number2 to Formula in Enterprise Custom Fields for Reporting in Project Online/ Project server.

[image: Creating new Enterprise Custom Field - 1]

[image: Creating new Enterprise Custom Field - 2]

In formula I am not able to find the property Text1 or Number1 to which I have given some values and I have to fetch them to calculate certain things for my report.

I user ProjectData to fetch the task details along with the custom fields.

Is there anyway that I could fetch these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextX, NumberX, .... are not available for reporting and - unfortunately - you can't even use it in a formula of an Enterprise Custom Field. From client, you are able to import a field like MyText1=[Text1] without error. But this formula will not work.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32d910ae-dfac-405b-9580-b8cac20e4da0/query-fields-like-quottext1quot-from-projects-in-project-online-pwa-using-power-bi?forum=projectonline